# drill down on reversed hierarchy gives incorrect results

Tags: mdx, iccube

I have got the following MDX statement in icCube (based on the standard Sales model):

```
with
set [time-set] as hierarchize({[Time].[Calendar].[All Periods],[Time].[Calendar].[Year].members,[Time].[Calendar].[Year].[2009].children},post)
member [issue] as [amount], caption = "drill down on 2008"
select [issue] on 0
,      [time-set] on 1
from sales
```

This gives the following result:
[image: result of MDX]

When clicked on 2008:

[image: result]

I assume the IDE is a bit mixed up since I have used the POST command. Is there a workaround to get it working as expected?

Comment: you have this in your [time-set] ....`[Time].[Calendar].[Year].[2009].Children`. Why are you specifying 2009?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer.

Sorry, the current version of iccube's pivot table is not supporting the post flag.